# apply style to excel file generated using office open xml C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've used Office OpenXML to generate XML file using windows service. The code works fine and excel file gets generated. But now I want to add some style to rows and cells. How can I achieve  that?
The code I've used is:

```
 if (thermoCoupleList.Count > 0)
 {
     FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
     using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
     {
           ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("ThermoCouples");
           // write some titles into row 1
           worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Thermocouple ID";
           worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value = "Calibration Done Date";
           worksheet.Cell(1, 3).Value = "Calibration Due Date";
           worksheet.Cell(1, 4).Value = "Company";
           int col, row = 1;
           foreach (Thermocouples tc1 in thermoCoupleList)
           {
                col = 1;
                row = row + 1;
                worksheet.Cell(row, col++).Value = Convert.ToString(tc1.ThermocoupleIdentification);
                worksheet.Cell(row, col++).Value = tc1.CalibrationDoneDate;
                worksheet.Cell(row, col++).Value = tc1.CalibrationDueDate;
                worksheet.Cell(row, col++).Value = tc1.Company;
           }

           xlPackage.Save();
     }
}
```

How can I achieve styling in Office OpenXML?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add style to your sheet 
Like this

```
private void AddStyles(Stylesheet styleSheet)
    {
        var patternFill = new PatternFill
        {
            PatternType = PatternValues.Solid,
            ForegroundColor = new ForegroundColor { Rgb = "FFFF0000" },
            BackgroundColor = new BackgroundColor { Indexed = 64U }
        };
        var fill = new Fill { PatternFill = patternFill };
        styleSheet.Fills.AppendChild(fill);
     }
```

Stylesheet object you can get for example in the following way

```
  using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FilePath, true))
        {
            var styleSheet= document.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet;
        }
```

Every of your styles will have some index. You can assign this style index to your cell. Use this property

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell.StyleIndex
```

Comment: Where to define this AddStyles function? And where to use it then?

Comment: You can do it where you want. For example i call this function when open document for modification. After this `using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FilePath, true))
        {
            var styleSheet= document.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet;` You should define this function inside class which made modifications to excel document

Comment: Can you please tell what namespace is to be included for Spreadsheet?

Comment: It seems for me that you want that i do all work for you. Are you software developer ? 1.Visual Studio hints about necessary namespaces 2. You can use F12 to get info you need 3. You can find that info at official OpenXML documentation. So at first try yourself

Comment: Well we both were referring different packages. You must be talking about EPPlus where as I was using ExcelPacage(OfficeOpenXML). In ExcelPacage, they do not have provided support for SpreadsheetDocument. Thanks btw :)

Comment: i talked about DocumentFormat.OpenXml dll (Open XML Format SDK 2.5)